# Binding to a blur event but wanting to stop it from firing in certain situations

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur

I have an object that has a bound *blur* event connected to it.   This allows me to write the contents of the object via ajax to a database and save edits.

```
editableText.bind('blur',function(e){
   blurFunction();
});
```

However I want to be able to quit the editing process by pressing escape.    So I have detection of the escape keypress working, that's fine.

```
editableText.on("keyup", function(e){
    if(e.which == 27){
        console.log("escape detected");
        $(this).blur();    
    }
});
```

My problem is that however I have tried to implement this, the blur is still being called, so this means that the changes are still saved even though I don't want them to be.

Comment: Can you provide code snippet?

Comment: Yes now added https://jsfiddle.net/arkid77/ax3xx8q0/.  In the fiddle currently the keyup isn't actually working.

Answer (score 1):

The following example will allow you to trigger something when the input element is blurred. Pressing escape however will blur the element without triggering the blur.

```js
function addBlur() {
  $('#input').blur(function (e) {
    console.log('blurring');
    //saving the results 
  });
}

$('#input').on("keyup", function(e){
    if(e.which == 27){
        console.log("escape detected");
     var el = $(this);
        el.off('blur');
        el.blur();
 addBlur();
    }
});

addBlur();
```

```html
<input id='input'>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/www0zcws/1/